# WPF DataGrid Radio Button Binding Issue

Tags: wpf

I am having RadioButton binding issue.Below is my xaml code.

```
<Grid Style="{DynamicResource MainFrameGrid1}">
<Grid Name="grdPCM">
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="407" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,102,0,0" Name="dgMI" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="781"
                      CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" 
                      SelectionUnit="Cell" EnableColumnVirtualization="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <RadioButton Name="rbM" GroupName="CMGrp" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SELECT, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Grid>
```

In code behind I am doing like this.
I am getting data from the database and storing it in the DataTable "dtMIData".Then I am temporarily adding a boolean column called  "SELECT" and assigning it to data grid like below in code behind.

```
DataColumn dcRB = new DataColumn("SELECT");
dcRB.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Boolean");
dcRB.DefaultValue = false;
dtMIData.Columns.Add(dcRB);
dtMIData.AcceptChanges();
dgMI.ItemsSource = dtMIData.AsDataView();
```

I am binding this new column "SELECT" with the RadioButton control.I want to select only one record,out of multiple retrieved records and want to retrieve the selected record in the code behind based on the "SELECT" column value.i.e."SELECT" column value is true.But even though RadioButton is checked,required binding column "SELECT" is not updating with value true.How to reflect the checked state in the related binding column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `DataGrid` the bindings do not get updated until you end editing of the row. Try adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the `RadioButton`'s binding expression to update bindings immediately:

```
<RadioButton Name="rbM" GroupName="CMGrp" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SELECT, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.mentioned solution is worked out for me.